# How to have an exception when using isalpha

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
{
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(argv[2]);i++)
  if(isalpha(argv[2][i]))
   {
    cout<<"X"<<endl;
    return (0);
   }
}
```

i don't want this to run if an exponential function is entered such as 1e10
any idea's????

p.s trying to distinguish numbers from non-numbers and want 1e10 (and similar) to count as numbers

Comment: I think you need to explain yourself a little better. It sounds like you are trying to distinguish numbers from non-numbers and you want 1e10 (and similar) to count as numbers?

Comment: yep that's exactly what i'm asking

Comment: Now you wrote "I don't want this to run for 1e10" and in next line "count 1e10 as number"... Give few examples of good and bad input.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be to use C++'s built in number parsing. Put `argv[2]` into a `istringstream` and then attempt to read it back as a `double`.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   istreamstream buf(argv[2]);
   double x;
   if (buf >> x)
   {
       cout << "argv[2] is a number and it's value is " << x << "\n";
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "argv[2] is not a number\n";
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Since the above is not completely correct (i.e. it's wrong) here another version that is hopefully more like what the OP was expecting. The function `is_a_number` will return true for any string that has the form of a normal floating point number, e.g. "1e10", "1.2", "-3", "1.2e-10" etc. etc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static bool is_a_number(const char* str);

int main()
{
    if (is_a_number(argv[2]))
    {
        cout << "its a number\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not a number\n";
    }
}

static bool is_a_number(const char* str)
{
    bool mant_digits = false, exp_digits = true;
    if (*str == '-' || *str == '+')
        ++str;
    while (isdigit((unsigned char)*str))
    {
        mant_digits = true;
        ++str;
    }
    if (*str == '.')
    {
        ++str;
        while (isdigit((unsigned char)*str))
        {
            mant_digits = true;
            ++str;
        }
    }
    if (*str == 'e' || *str == 'E')
    {
        ++str;
        if (*str == '-' || *str == '+')
            ++str;
        exp_digits = false;
        while (isdigit((unsigned char)*str))
        {
            exp_digits = true;
            ++str;
        }
    }
    return *str == '\0' && mant_digits && exp_digits;
}
```

Comment: @AshFernando Yes but it's much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This first tests if the input is in the correct format and then performs conversion. In case of invalid input it throws an `std::runtime_error` exception.

```
class CommandLine
{
public:
    CommandLine(int argc, char*argv[]) : 
        locale(""), arguments(argv, argv+ argc)
    {
       if (argc < 3)
           throw std::runtime_error("not enough arguments.");
    }

    double GetValueXYZ()
    {
        if (!IsValidInput(arguments[2]))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                arguments[2] + " is invalid input for XYZ.");
        return std::strtod(arguments[2].c_str(), nullptr);
        // You could use a stringstream instead
    }

private:
    bool IsValidInput(const std::string& arg)
    {
        const auto& numpunct = std::use_facet<std::numpunct<char>>(locale);
        auto err = std::find_if(begin(arg), end(arg), [&](char c)
        {
            return !(std::isdigit(c, locale) || 
                c == numpunct.thousands_sep() ||
                c == numpunct.decimal_point());
        });
        return err == end(arg);
    }

    std::locale locale;
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
};


int main()
{
    char*argv[] = { "main", "2.34" , "1.10"};
    try
    {
        CommandLine cmd(3, argv);
        std::cout << cmd.GetValueXYZ();
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```